# creating combinations of obstacles in a 2D side scroller game

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, 2d, allegro5

My first game in ALLEGRO 5 with c++.

It has a player that keeps moving continuously in right direction. From the right edge of the screen player faces obstacles like triangles and squares. These obstacles come alive at right edge of screen and die at left edge of screen.

Suppose X is triangle and O is square.

i want to create them in few combinations like

..{x} {xo} {xoox} {oxxo} {oxx}... And some variations(random maybe)

And after that I will randomize the occurence of these pattern.

SO I found a method to implement what i wanted. I used a switch() to randomly select various cases of combination. It works pretty well. But once in a while it overlaps even after I introduced a minimum gap xoff

Here is the code:

```
`//I have used srand(time(NULL)); once in main function too.


   if(state == PLAYING)
        {

            ball->Moveball();
                ball->Jumpball();

                //Camera-----------
                ball->Cameraupdate();
                al_identity_transform(&camera);
                al_translate_transform(&camera,-Cameraposition[0],-Cameraposition[1]);
                al_use_transform(&camera);



                if(rand() % 200==0)
                {

                     xoff+=200;// to introduce a minimum gap between them but this also fail once in a while.
                    int ch;
                    ch=rand()%4;
                        switch(ch)
                        {

                        case 0:
                        //T

                        triangle = new Triangle(850 + Cameraposition[0]+xoff,319);
                        objects.push_back(triangle);
                        triangle->SetAlive(true);

                        break;

                        case 1:
                        //TT

                        triangle = new Triangle(850 + Cameraposition[0]+xoff,319);
                        objects.push_back(triangle);
                        triangle->SetAlive(true);
                        triangle = new Triangle(850 +30+ Cameraposition[0]+xoff,319);
                        objects.push_back(triangle);
                        triangle->SetAlive(true);
                        break;

                        case 2:
                        //S

                        square = new Square(850 + Cameraposition[0]+xoff,310);
                        objects.push_back(square);
                        square->SetAlive(true);

                        break;

                        case 3:
                        //SS

                        square = new Square(850 + Cameraposition[0]+xoff,310);
                        objects.push_back(square);
                        square->SetAlive(true);
                        square = new Square(850 +82+ Cameraposition[0]+xoff,310);
                        objects.push_back(square);
                        square->SetAlive(true);

                        break;

                        }

                }
`
```

> Problem solved :(For those who experienced similar doubt)The above code solves the problem of creating random combination of obstacles and generating those combinations randomly. But do check for collisions if you don't want to get overlapping combinations.

Comment: You have bugs, like the second `else if(triangle->GetAlive() == false)`, which should be `else if(square->GetAlive() == false`.

Comment: Holy moly! :O I am stupid of a special kind. XD
Lets hope its the same problem. brb

Comment: Nope, problem still there. Its like if you cut that overlapping vertically from middle we will have two proper half pieces of triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another for loop:

```
void createObstacles(int numObstacles)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numObstacles; i++)
    {
        if(rand() % 2 == 0)
        {
            // Create a triangle.
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a square.
        }
    }
}
```

Call this every time you want to create obstacles, controlling the number of objects released at one time by changing the parameter `numObstacles`.

You can now do:

```
if(rand() % 200 == 0)
{
    // Create anywhere from 1 to maxToCreate (which is 4) obstacles at a time.
    const int maxToCreate = 4;
    int numToCreate = (rand() % maxToCreate) + 1;

    // Call the function to make some obstacles.
    createObstacles(numToCreate);
}
```

Since your shapes are overlapping, either fix your initialization code to initialize them the way

Comment: Keeler, I gave a try . But instead of coming in combos either squares are overlapping the triangles or triangles are overlapping the squares. In both cases their x & y cooordinates are same.

Comment: I think there is some conflict between creation of triangles and that of squares. No triangle overlaps other triangle. No Square overlaps other square. But either triangle overlap a square which is already drawn, OR a square overlaps an already drawn triangle. Can you see any error in my triangle/square creation code?

Comment: You're using a lot of 'magic numbers'. All those instances of 15 and 40 in your bounds checking look suspicious and inconsistent. You test a lot of stuff in those if statements, but you haven't documented what you're actually checking for there.

Comment: If you're going to add code, add it to your original question so it's easy for everyone to see.

Comment: i reworked on code. uploading it instead. Last one was not correct method to achieve i guess.

Comment: I wouldn't want someone else who searches for a problem same as me on the site, to get to a wrong code.